# How do you use docker-compose from a Gitlab Registry on DigitalOcean?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab

Every time I try to `docker pull registry.gitlab.com/our/private/registry` I get an error `Error: image our/private/registry:latest not found`.

So how can i pull our containers from the gitlab registry?

#### **What I have done:**

> 1) Have a digital ocean droplet with docker installed
>
> 2) Not sure if it maters but I installed `gitlabci-multi-runner`

Comment: Did you run `docker login` first ?

Comment: Yes I did run login. Specifically `docker login registry.gitlab.com`